# Does inverse exist for the mapping given below?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given $F(x,y,z)=(yz, x^2)$ find $F^{-1}(0,0)$. This Question is from Schaum's linear algebra. Here author solves it by setting $x^2 = 0$ and $yz = 0$ solving for $x = 0$ and either of $y = 0$ or $z = 0$ implying that  $z-axis$ or $y-axis$ as solutions.

However, I have below reasoning. If we solve for $F(x,y,z) = (0,0)$ then we get vectors such as $(0,t,0)$ or $(0,0,p)$ where $t\neq0$ and $p\neq0$ this means that $Ker{F}$ contains vectors other than $zero$ vector. So $F$ is singular. Then how come we are able to solve for $F^{-1}$?

Please help me understand where I am incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're slightly misunderstanding what's asked.

You are correct in that, vectors of the form $(0,t,0)$ and $(0,0,p)$ are indeed such that $F$ maps them to $0$. Being "non-singular" as you say, refers to a matrix/linear map being invertible, or equivalently, having non-zero determinant.

In linear algebra, we define the kernel of a **linear map** $f:V\to W$ between finite dimensional vector spaces, as the set of vectors mapped to $0$ by $f$. This turns out to be a vector subspace of $V$. When $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension, it makes sense to speak of $\det(f)$, and we say $f$ is non singular when $\det(f)$ is non zero. This happens to be equivalent to $\ker f = \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$ when $V,W$ have the same dimension.

In your case, $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R^2}$ is not a linear map, hence the above constructions break down. First $\ker f$ is no longer a vector subspace (why?), and the notion of determinant is no longer defined. But even when the map is not a linear map, we can still ask questions such as what is $F^{-1}(0,0)$. The notation $F^{-1}$ might be misleading though, because as $F$ is not a bijection, there is not a well defined inverse $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R^3}$, instead, $F^{-1}$ is a map from the $P(\mathbb{R}^2)\to P(\mathbb{R^3})$ ( $P$ denotes the powerset of a set, i.e. it's set of subsets), that takes a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and outputs the set $F^{-1}(S)=\left\lbrace (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3, F(x,y,z) \in S \right\rbrace$, i.e. the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are mapped by $F$ to $S$, this set is called the inverse image of $S$ by $F$.

In your case $S$ is just $\left\lbrace (0,0) \right\rbrace $, hence the slight abuse of notation $F^{-1}(0,0)$ instead of $F^{-1}(\left\lbrace (0,0) \right\rbrace)$. Finally, finding this set, is a matter of solving a system of equations :

$$F(x,y,z)=0\iff \left\lbrace\begin{align*}
yz &= 0 \\ 
x^2 &= 0 
\end{align*}\right. \iff (x=0) \text{ and } (y=0 \text{ or } z=0)$$

Hope this helps clear up any confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed explanation. It all makes sense now.